# Google Mocking Framework Matcher Elements Array comparision

Tags: c++, googletest, matcher, googlemock

I have a google test that make a call

```
EXPECT_THAT(unit.OnEndStartup(), ::testing::ElementsAre(
       IsEvent(Result::NoError,Type::S , ""),
       IsEvent(Result::NoError,Type::N , ""),
       IsEvent(Result::NoError,Type::E , ""),
       IsEvent(Result::NoError,Type::C , "")
));
```

`IsEvent` is a `MATCHER_P2` defined below.

```
unit.OnEndStartup() returns vector<Info> where struct Info { 
       Result result;
       PackageType type;
       std::string newVersion;



 inline bool operator==(Info e1)
    {
        return (e1.result == result
                && e1.package == package
                && e1.newVersion == newVersion);
    }
   }
```

The `EXPECT_THAT()` call is used in multiple places across the file. I am looking for a sensible way to refactor out multiple calls to IsEvent().

I have defined

```
std::array<Info, 4> expected_default_list = {
        Info(Result::NoError, Type::S, ""),
        Info(Result::NoError, Type::N, ""),
        Info(Result::NoError, Type::E, ""),
        Info(Result::NoError, Type::C, "")
};


EXPECT_THAT(unit.OnEndStartup(), ::testing::ElementsAreArray(expected_default_list));
```

This is giving template errors. is my approach in refactoring the code correct?
The error that I am getting is

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const Info’ and ‘const Info’)
   bool operator()(const A& a, const B& b) const { return a == b; }
```

Comment: Is equality defined for `Info`?

Comment: @Yang- I have `operator==` defined. Please see updated code

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: @Yang - Please see error above. for some reason it is not recognizing `operator==`

Comment: In your `operator==`, can you try to make the parameter `const EventInfo& e1`?

Comment: @Yang- I tried it. Surprisingly I am getting the same error.

Comment: Did you define it in `Info` or `EventInfo`? You need to define it in `Info`, and take `const Info& e1`.

Comment: sorry I defnied it in `Info`. There is not struct called `EventInfo` now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193805/discussion-between-yang-and-liv2hak).